# What does "illuminatrix" mean?

Tags: nouns

Just like the title. I noticed this word when I was reading a game's art book, in which the sentence goes:

> Feeling down? Bring the sunshine inside with Henderson’s new Illuminatrix. ([Source, at the bottom of page 1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hWNBEvMFt8_s4ZwHw_lxnHuBGaJy35DqWsRuHCAOqj0/edit))

I googled it yet there seems to have nothing that matches the sentence. Is it a misspelled one (it looks so similar to "**illumination**") or it does exist?

Comment: Following your link it is fairly obvious that the writer has set the game in a fantasy environment. In fact it has echoes to me of His Dark Materials. The line is also a throw-away line of audible advertising written  into the book. Either it is just mood-setting or the concept of an illuminatrix will be introduced later. It's specific to the game and the art book, it's not a concept in the outside world.

Comment: @BoldBen Seems like this word only appears in this sentence (1 matched word only). According to the community, this is only a leaked scratch of the artbook, which is incomplete; wonder if they'll fix that when the book is released officially. But still thanks for you commenting, and you're right, probably it's just a noun that only appears in the game and/or the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-trix" is the female equivalent of "-tor". It's called the agential suffix and comes from Latin. A gladiatrix is a female gladiator and presumably an illuminatrix is a female illuminator. Illuminators did the illustrations for medieval bibles. I don't know if they get much work nowadays.

Alternatively, she might put up lights somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like most other "trixes," I doubt whether *executrix* is used much nowadays. We are introduced to an executrix in this novel's very first sentence:

> One summer afternoon Mrs Oedipa Maas came home from a Tupperware party whose hostess had put perhaps too much kirsch in the fondue to
> find that she, Oedipa, had been names executor, or she supposed
> **executrix**, of the estate of one Pierce Inverarity, a California real estate mogul who had once lost two million dollars in his spare
> time but still had assets numerous and tangled enough to make the job
> of sorting it out more than honorary. [Thomas Pynchon; *The Crying of
> Lot 49*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Crying_of_Lot_49/zUYOEp5uXYYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=too%20much%20kirsch) (1965)

> **executrix** (n.)
>
> a woman who is an executor [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/executrix)

Another "trix" you still encounter from time to time (perhaps only in writing or on the screen) is *dominatrix*; however, she wouldn't likely appear in that role at a Tupperware party.

> **dominatrix** (n.)
>
> A woman who physically or psychologically dominates her partner in a
> sadomasochistic encounter [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominatrix)

I don't know if there are other "trixes" that have no *easily recognized* male equivalent. I assume *dominator* would be understood as the male counterpart only in an appropriate context.

Another one that comes readily to mind is

> **aviatrix**
>
> A woman who is an aviator [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aviatrix)

*Aviatrix: The Story of Amelia Earhart* by Paul Briand Jr. (2014)

Comment: FWIW, the terms testatrix (a woman who writes a will) and executrix (a woman who administers the estate of a deceased person) have largely been removed in the past few decades from legal usage. The preferred usage is now "testator" (gender neutral term for person who writes a will) and personal representative (gender neutral term for a person who administers a decedent's estate, generally abbreviated P.R. in speech, to displace the latinate "executor" despite the fact that the latinate word is more widely understood), in most of the U.S.